# How do I make this tag a clickable inside the input?

Tags: html, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

I loaded to my project nice input and my goal is to put inside this input the clickable button/a tag with float:right. Inside my local version of this, after clicking the button/a tag(question mark) animation start to happen, in jsfiddle example it doesn't even react. I don't have any ideas how to solve this problem, not changing the input source(design is cool).

https://jsfiddle.net/yoofu5me/5/

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <span class="input input--haruki text-center" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <input class="input__field input__field--haruki" type="text" id="input-1" />
            <label class="input__label input__label--haruki" for="input-1">
                <span style="font-size:14px;" class="input__label-content input__label-content--haruki">Give me the word <a href="https://www.freshdesignweb.com/css-login-form-templates/" target="_blank" style="float:right" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-question"></i></a></span>
            </label>

        </span>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Not clear where do you want to click on.

Comment: on the question mark

Comment: There is a `pointer-event: none;` css rule set on the label. It works when you remove this. But maybe it is there for a good reason?

Comment: If you want do it with server side just pust your content in form tag but if you i want use js just do onclick on element

Comment: One more thing, you have two `href` tags within the `<a...>` element. Remove one.

Comment: thanks, i have no idea about why this css rule has been set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pointer-event: none;` CSS rule is set on the parent element of the link (question mark).

Removing this rule solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is - you haven't linked the css with your html file.

The link that you've provided also has a CSS. Save that in styles.css. Then go to your HTML file - add this in  tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```